# Looping logic catching unknown limit value

Tags: php

I can't write anymore condition, but I can't use while loop because I don't know the max int of the $_GET["pageNumber"]. I have to write ugly code like below

```
switch ($_GET["pageNumber"]) {
    case 3:
         $_GET["pageNumber"] = 40;
        break;
    case 4:
        $_GET["pageNumber"] = 60;
        break;
    case 5:
        $_GET["pageNumber"] = 80;
        break;
    case 6:
        $_GET["pageNumber"] = 100;
    break;
    default:
        $_GET["pageNumber"] = 20;
}
```

Any better way to handle this case?

Comment: I think you have somewhere wrong logic. If you get variable and you check it's value to change himself, than maybe you just need to pass correct value instead. Please provide full idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `pageNumber` isset, and if it is, check that it contains only digits. If it does, just multiple its value by 20, then subtract 20 to get the correct offset:

```
if (isset($_GET['pageNumber']) && ctype_digit($_GET['pageNumber']) && $_GET['pageNumber'] > 2) {
  $_GET['pageNumber'] = $_GET['pageNumber'] * 20 - 20; 
} else {
  $_GET['pageNumber'] = 20;
}
```

Comment: I knew there's some math in this!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `switch` statement, you can use `array indexes` as better option.

Everytime, you need to add a new condition, you need to append an array element with

a pre-defined key and value.

```
<?php
$pageNumbers = array();
$pageNumbers[3] = 40;
$pageNumbers[4] = 60;
$pageNumbers[5] = 80;
$pageNumbers[6] = 100;
$pageNumber = ! empty($pageNumbers[$_GET['pageNumber']) ? $pageNumbers[$_GET['pageNumber'] : 20;
?>
```